# Can i create a function with variable parameters in C?

Tags: c, functions

I've always wondered where a single function such as `printf();` can take in variable parameters and provide the right results. For example,

```
printf("Number is %d",a);
```

which has two parameters, and

```
printf("Numbers are %d and %d",a,b);
```

which has three variables.
So, is there any possibilities for creating a user-defined function like these functions in C? If so, how can i do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is known as a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Comment: [Related](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264089/why-do-we-have-to-tell-printf-the-type-of-data-in-c/264098#264098).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly, the C standard defines *what* variadic function declarations should look like, but no guidance in *how* to implement them.

The mechanics for accessing arguments to variadic functions are therefore implementation-dependent. [GNU C provides this via stdarg.h](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html).

Comment: There is a small example on the `va_start` man page.

Comment: Actually, the macros in stdarg.h are *the* standard way for accessing arguments in variadic functions. The thing left open by the standard is how those macros should be implemented.

Comment: (and the macros are guaranteed to be provided by a compliant compiler, so you don't need to worry about it - writing and using variadic functions is perfectly well-defined)